# Insert custom logo action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to insert drawable in the middle of the action bar instead of the title. Is there some example or somebody can help me? Thank you.

I have done like this `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MyTitle");` but I want a drawable instead of the title, how can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getActionBar().setCustomView(View v)`. This View will be displayed

> between the application icon and any action buttons and may use any space available there.

(from the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView(android.view.View)))

Just use a `ImageView` for  `setCustomView` and the title will be replaced with any image you want.

**Note** if you want to hide the icon that's displayed at the left by default, use `getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);`